# What further action I should take on this specific question if my flag is aged away?

Tags: support, flags, specific-question

I recently flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777898/5779732) because it was off-topic.

Following is the **complete** question body:

> Apart from Fabio Maulo's few blog posts, are there any other sites with examples and/or documentation on the new NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code feature?

This is clearly off-topic. So I raised a flag which aged away.

I read other posts on meta; those explain how flags age away, what "aged-away" means and also that it is nothing bad for me. But this is not what I am asking here.

If my flag is aged away, what **next** action can I take to close/delete the question. I am a <3K user; so I cannot cast a close vote. I cannot raise the same flag anymore.

Should I raise a moderator flag? Or something else?

Comment: Don't raise a moderator flag. Instead seek help from other 3k+ users to close the post (if it truly merits closing). The [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is a nice place to start, but read their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/) first.

Comment: These links are also helped me while chatting on SOCVR.  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting, https://socvr.org/faq and https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests

Comment: The question seems 100% on-topic.  The reason the flag aged away is the flag was wrong, the question is a good one.  It appears the question has now been incorrectly closed due to the "meta effect" (ie, folks who have no involvement/understanding one way or another, attempting to help by voting "as meta"...)

Comment: Thank goodness, the question and excellent answers are still there (with 50,000 views - everyone just ignores the whacky "closed" status on SO.  Popular is popular. Information wants to be free.)

Comment: (That being said, of course the QA is utterly useless, since it is over three years old.  Anything, at all, over three years old in relation to computers is usually utterly useless.  This is the "elephant in the room" that SO continues to pretend it can't see, which is funny :) )

Comment: @Fattie the question is absolutely off topic. We have a close reason just for this type of question: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the options, which [I have done now](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40590016#40590016), is to ask [SOCVR](https://socvr.org) to help closing the question. From their [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#can-i-request-people-to-vote-or-flag-on-posts-i-find):

> #### Can I request people to vote or flag on posts I find?
>
> ...
>
> **Close Vote Requests** are the most common request you'll find. Please follow the format a few sections above. Too make sure people don't abuse the system, we ask that you keep cv-pls'ing to a minimum until you have 3k rep for yourself.

To rephrase the last sentence: do this only *incidentally* until you have the [privilege to cast close votes yourself](/help/privileges/close-questions). Once you have that privilege, you're kindly requested to help with other close vote requests as well.

> Should I raise a moderator flag?

As Bhargav Rao notes in the comments, don't do this. The flag says *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator.* and this is something the community can handle on its own.

Comment: The question is now closed; it's hard to tell whether that is because of the Meta effect or the [cv-pls], as SOCVR regulars are often active on Meta as well.

Comment: We're not 100% to blame this time ...

Comment: I don't expect everyone to be fully up to date with our rules but [rule 11](https://socvr.org/faq#GEfM-cv-pls-not-a-habit) has a subrule that CV-pls are welcome for questions that *have recent activity on the question (Edits, VLQ/NAA answer)*. For the question at hand that doesn't seem the case so strictly speaking it could have bounced when that cv-pls was posted. But sometimes we're nice ...

Comment: *edits question to make it recently active* </jk>